# Populating an array of custom model crashes in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

There is a variable in my class. which is the array of a custom model. I want to populate this variable in method 1. but app crashes at this line: `[inboxMessagesArray addObject:entity]`

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS

In .m file:

```
@synthesize inboxMessagesArray;
```

In .h file:

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray<InboxMessagesResponseEntity *> *inboxMessagesArray;
```

### Mehod1

```
for (NSDictionary *responseEntityDictionary in dictionary)
{ 
   InboxMessagesResponseEntity *entity = [[InboxMessagesResponseEntity alloc] initWithDictionary:responseEntityDictionary error:&err]; 
   [inboxMessagesArray addObject:entity];
}
```

Comment: Do you have an error message in console?

Answer (score 1):

You need to init the array `inboxMessagesArray` before adding objects to it

```
 self.inboxMessagesArray = [NSMutableArray new];  // OR [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```